# Check if a number is a double or an int

Tags: java, double, int

I am trying to beautify a program by displaying 1.2 if it is 1.2 and 1 if it is 1 problem is I have stored the numbers into the arraylist as doubles. How can I check if a Number is a double or int?

Comment: Can you clarify whether you mean any whole number or you want only 32-bit signed `int` values?

Answer (score 22):

Well, you can use:

```
if (x == Math.floor(x))
```

or even:

```
if (x == (long) x) // Performs truncation in the conversion
```

If the condition is true, i.e. the body of the `if` statement executes, then the value is an integer. Otherwise, it's not.

Note that this will view 1.00000000001 as still a double - if these are values which have been *computed* (and so may just be "very close" to integer values) you may want to add some tolerance. Also note that this will start failing for very large integers, as they can't be exactly represented in `double` anyway - you may want to consider using `BigDecimal` instead if you're dealing with a very wide range.

EDIT: There are better ways of approaching this - using `DecimalFormat` you should be able to get it to only *optionally* produce the decimal point. For example:

```
import java.text.*;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.###");

        double[] values = { 1.0, 3.5, 123.4567, 10.0 };

        for (double value : values)
        {
            System.out.println(df.format(value));
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1
3.5
123.457
10
```

Comment: @chuck: It will check whether the value that you've given is exactly an integer.

Comment: +1: floor rounds the number to a whole number.  Only whole numbers are unchanged so if its the same, it must have been a whole number. BTW:  I assume you mean any whole number not a 32-bit signed `int` as such.

Comment: btw it doesn't work for integers outside MIN_VALUE<n || n>MAX_VALUE

Comment: @bestsss, what's MIN_ and MAX_VALUE?

Comment: @aioobe: Yes, that's printed `false` twice - in other words, it's considering it as a double. It would print true if it considered it to be an integer.

Comment: @bestsss: Not particularly obviously - I wondered whether you meant Long.MAX_VALUE.

Comment: @bestss, I assumed you meant `Long` as Jon had talked about the limitations of using `if (num == (long) num)` ;)

Comment: @Jon, also (for instance floor(+-inf)==+-inf). Since the lower range of int than long and I expect the OP to convert to  (int) it won't work.

Comment: @Peter, double cannot hold all values of long (via normal conversion) but it can do so for int, so if initially a long is stored in double, the value might have been already lost.

Comment: @bestsss, this is true. Not all double values can be stored in as long either. Using a (long) instead of a (int) means that larger values will have the expected behaviour, however using `floor`, `round` or `ceil` is the safest option.

Answer (score 3):

Another simple & intuitive solution using the modulus operator (%)

```
if (x % 1 == 0)  // true: it's an integer, false: it's not an integer
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively one can use this method too, I found it helpful.

```
double a = 1.99; 
System.out.println(Math.floor(a) == Math.ceil(a));
```

Answer (score -1):

I am C# programmer so I tested this in .Net. This should work in Java too (other than the lines that use the Console class to display the output.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double[] values = { 1.0, 3.5, 123.4567, 10.0, 1.0000000003 };
        int num = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++ )
        {
            num = (int) values[i];
            // compare the difference against a very small number to handle 
            // issues due floating point processor
            if (Math.Abs(values[i] - (double) num) < 0.00000000001)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(num);
            }
            else // print as double
            {
                Console.WriteLine(values[i]);
            }
        }
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```